# MongoServerError: command createIndexes requires authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am having trouble getting my current NodeJS project to connect to my MongoDB database which has security authorization enabled in the conf file.

I am using Mongoose.js to connect to the db. After reading the documentation I can't seem to figure out what I have missed.

error: MongoServerError: command createIndexes requires authentication

I thank you in advance for your assistance! :)

Here's my implementation below:

I created a db user which has read / write roles on the project database.

```
{
    _id: 'admin.dbUser',
    userId: UUID("1dfdd059-dc4e-48c8-82af-3b9d3b6106fc"),
    user: 'dbUser',
    db: 'admin',
    credentials: {
      'SCRAM-SHA-1': {
        iterationCount: 10000,
        salt: 'blah',
        storedKey: 'blah',
        serverKey: 'blah'
      },
      'SCRAM-SHA-256': {
        iterationCount: 15000,
        salt: 'blah',
        storedKey:'blah' ,
        serverKey: 'blah'
      }
    },
    roles: [
      { role: 'readWrite', db: 'projectDbLocal' },
      { role: 'read', db: 'projectDbLocal' }
    ]
  },
```

In my app.js file I have the following code:

I have also made sure that my app.js is able to parse the environment variables storing the mongo credentials.

```
//Set MongoDB options
const db_options = {
  authSource: 'admin',
  auth: {
    username: process.env.MONGODBUSER,
    password: process.env.MONGODBPASS,
  },
  useNewURLParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};

//Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODBURL, db_options);

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Database Connected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out what was happening here.

I am using MongoStore for managing sessions. The store that was being created was not being authenticated which is why I was having issues.

The resulting code that got this working was:

```
const sessionConfig = {
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: MongoStore.create({
    mongoUrl: `mongodb://${mongodbUser}:${mongodbPass}@${process.env.MONGODBURL}/db`,
  }),
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    //secure: true,
    expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, //one week
    maxAge: 180 * 60 * 1000,
  },
};
```